# Mistakenly had nano at the beginning of ps -e | grep ssh-agent

Tags: zsh, macos, ssh-agent

Like I said in the title, I accidentally ran this:

`nano ps -e | grep ssh-agent`

Now when I properly run `ps -e | grep ssh-agent` I see this:

```
# ps -e | grep ssh-agent
 1613 ??         0:00.05 /usr/bin/ssh-agent -l
27195 ttys000    0:00.00 grep ssh-agent
```

I had to terminate the session to get out of the command state that left me in. In hindsight I suppose I could have just ran it again.

Here's what I tried:

```
# ssh-agent -k
unset SSH_AUTH_SOCK;
unset SSH_AGENT_PID;
```

I then got:

```
SSH_AGENT_PID not set, cannot kill agent
```

So then I tried:

`ps -ef | grep ssh-agent`

Now I have this:

```
# ps -ef | grep ssh-agent
  501  1613     1   0 Sun07PM ??         0:00.06 /usr/bin/ssh-agent -l
  501 27629 26750   0 12:06PM ttys000    0:00.01 grep ssh-agent
```

Can someone help me correct this? I don't want to mess with it further, as this is not an area that I'm familiar with.

Comment: Have you tried kill -9 1613?

Comment: @ilkkachu This is macOS. You should not `kill 1613`. That's a perfectly normal ssh-agent process that goes with the session. There are no “lost” environment variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version of nano on macOS doesn't like it when its standard output is a pipe. Well, no big deal. Just kill it. Open another terminal tab and run

```
pgrep nano
```

If the output is a single number, there's only this one nano process, so kill it.

```
pkill nano
```

If `pgrep` shows multiple processes, you need to determine which one to kill. Run

```
ps -eww |grep nano
```

Look for the line that contains with `nano ps -e`. The first number on that line is the process ID. Copy-paste that number and pass it to the `kill` command. For example, if you see

```
27629 ttys000    0:00.00 nano ps -e
```

then run

```
kill 27629
```

The grep process will die automatically when the left-hand side of the pipe dies.

You could have done all this and gotten your terminal back. You can still doing it now, it'll kill some useless processes (but of course it won't bring your terminal back).

Having an ssh-agent process running is normal. It goes with your macOS session. You shouldn't run `ssh-agent -k` on macOS, and the system doesn't set `SSH_AGENT_PID` so that if you do run `ssh-agent -k` it won't actually do anything.

Comment: `pgrep nano` returns nothing. If I just try to kill the process I get `failed: no such process`

Comment: @MikeCiffone Well, then now it's already dead, and you have nothing else to do.

Comment: _But_ `ps -eww | grep nano` *does* give me a process ID: `31355 ttys000    0:00.00 grep nano`. PID changed after I tried killing 27629 26750). I knew not to kill 1613 per your comment but good looks.

Comment: `ps -eww | grep nano` is returning the grep command itself -- you're grepping for commands that include "nano" in the command line and "grep nano" includes "nano" as one of its arguments. The PID keeps changing because each time you run the command it's a different grep process.